# Unable to get second line of Regex for 5th number and always after the word Serial Number

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I am trying to use Regex to get the serial numbers which is always equal to five and always contains the word SerialNumber

I have the following:

```
(?=)SerialNumber\n*\d{5}(?<=)
```

The text looks like this:

```
SerialNumber             
00330-80000-00000-AA622  

SerialNumber             
1313311313-13345
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

[image]

Comment: Can you show say three matching serial numbers and three non matching serial numbers?

Comment: you want to capture whole line after SerialNumber i.e, `00330-80000-00000-AA622` right?

Comment: @AshishRanjan Correct, I want all the Serial Numbers in the text.  So 00330-80000-00000-AA622 as well as all the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

`SerialNumber\s*\K\S*`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QKR0gI/3)

**Explanation:**

- `SerialNumber\s*` - matches the text `SerialNumber` followed by 0+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `\K` - Forget everything matched so far
- `\S*` - match 0+ occurences of any character which is not a whitespace character.

Comment: Is there a way to write that without the \K?  I'm pretty sure the software I use does not support that unfortunately.

Comment: @BarryLance Notepad++ supports `\K`. If you are not using NP++ please tag your question correctly.

Comment: @BarryLance If you don't want \K, then you will have to get the required text from group1 of this regex [`(?<=SerialNumber)\s*(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/QKR0gI/4)

Comment: Nearly, it is still including spacing.   It current looks like this: https://ibb.co/gMQWMR

Comment: @BarryLance You will get your required data from Group1 of the whole match. The group will not be having those spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure I get that completely.  Hmm hopefully those spaces don't give me grief later, but this is about as good as it gets considering no \K

Answer (score 1):

A regex using positive lookbehind :

```
(?<=SerialNumber\n)(\S+)
```

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AQ0YYZ/1)